# react axios delete result data not movement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, rest

```
try {
  const removeFile = fileChips ? .filter((file) => file !== fileId);
  setFileChips(removeFile)

  let result = await Axios.delete(
    'http://api.pds.com:3000/api/v1/files?ver=v1', {
      params: {
        FL_IDS: [fileId]
      }
    }
  );
  console.log(result)
  refetch()

} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

I want to get the value of the execution result after Axios runs. Both get and post receive result values with similar codes, but delete does not receive result values. Delete of execution result is normal. If the deletion is normal, we are promised to get an OK sign at the back end. However, no results appear on the console. What's the cause?

Comment: Try logging `console.log(result.data)`

Comment: not working....

Comment: have you imported axios correctly ?

Comment: My boss is managing it. When asked once, they said that they had to send out the result. I don't know why I can't get the data even though it's deleted normally when I perform the deletion. Maybe it's wrong at the back end?